Azure Pipelines - Replace a variable in a yaml file
I have a deployment pipeline that uses a Kubernetes task:
          - task: Kubernetes@1
            displayName: 'Apply deployment'
            inputs:
              connectionType: '***'
              namespace: '***'
              command: 'apply'
              useConfigurationFile: true
              configuration: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy/kube/api/deployment.yaml'
              secretType: 'generic'

This task uses another yaml file (deployment.yaml)
I would like to vary some data in my deployment.yaml
For this I tested Yaml writer
Which works well except for resource tables.
Example:
I have in deployment.yaml:
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: 'imageVersion'

I want to change the 'image' property, which gives us spec.template.spec.containers[0].image
          - task: YamlWriter@0
            inputs:
              file: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy/kube/api/deployment.yaml'
              set: "spec.template.spec.containers['api'].image='my-image:latest'"

The value is replaced, however it also adds 'containers[0]': {} at the end of deployment.yaml.
How to fix this / do you have any alternatives that can solve this need without using a script with the sed command?
Thanks a lot 

It might be easier to use the Replace Tokens for this particular case. The task replaces tokens in text based files with variable values
See the examples)
and How to use Replace Tokens in Azure Pipelines.

I can reproduce the same situation when using the Yaml Writer task in Azure Pipelines. It will add additional value 'containers[0]': {} at the end of the YAML file. It seems that it cannot correctly handle the contents of the resource table inside the Yaml file.

How to fix this / do you have any alternatives that can solve this need without using a script with the sed command?

To meet your requirement, you can change to use the following methods:
Method1: you can try to use the Replace Token task from Replace Tokens Extension.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Add placeholder character in the yaml file with the format: ${PipelinevariableName}#
For example:
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: '#{APIimageversion}#'

Step2: In Azure Pipeline, you can add the replace token task and set the Pipeline variable(the same name as the name in placeholder character).
For example:
variables:
  APIimageversion: my-image:latest

- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@6
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    root: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy/kube/api'
    sources: deployment.yaml

Result:

Method2: If you don't want to use placeholder character in YAML file, you can use the RegEx Match & Replace task from RegEx Match & Replace extension.
This task will use regular expressions to match fields in the file.
Here is an example:
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: api
          image: 'imageVersion'

Task sample:
steps:
- task: RegExMatchReplace@2
  displayName: 'RegEx Match & Replace'
  inputs:
    PathToFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deploy/kube/api/deployment.yaml
    RegEx: "image: '[A-Za-z]+'"
    ValueToReplace: "image: 'my-image:latest'"

You can use this site to convert the regular expressions : Regex Generator

Thank you so much!
I used the Replace Tokens extension which works perfectly, and in terms of writing it is just as simple as Yaml Writer.
For those who see this subject, the variables to replace must be in the variables part, the parameters are not taken into account.
Don't panic, just create a variable that takes the value of the parameter.
